# listview viewholder pattern. where to settag for position on removing an item. android

Tags: android, listview

I see that the viewholder pattern is good for smooth scrolling, but I have ran into an error with the pattern.  If one deletes an item from the listview then the tags are are a little messed up.  Therefore, deleting a second item doesn't delete the one an user clicked on, but deletes whichever the previous tag was set on.  In the code example below, is where I have set the tag for the button's position okay or does it break the viewholder paradigm? Does anyone have a better way of removing items?  How do you do it? Example:

```
public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent )
    {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if( v == null )
        {
            LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.fpc_contents_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.delete   = (Button)  v.findViewById( R.id.row_delete );
            v.findViewById( R.id.fpc_contents_row_delete ).setOnClickListener( global_onClickListener );
                    //used to set position tag here.  (deleted wrong items after the first delete)
                    //i.e)  holder.delete.setTag( position );
            v.setTag( holder );
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        //setting the tag here then delete functionality works just fine.
        holder.delete.setTag( position );
        holder.name.setText( fpcItems.get(position).item0.name );
        return v;
    }

final  OnClickListener global_onClickListener = new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick( final View view ) 
        {
            switch( view.getId() ) 
            {
            case R.id.fpc_contents_row_delete :
                int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
                arraylist.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();                                
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you're going to set the tag on an object in the holder, you'll need to do it outside of your `(v == null)` conditional.

If you don't, the tag will only be set on new views, not on recycled ones. If, say, a list item three rows down uses a recycled view instead of inflating a brand new one, it will have the position tag of whatever position was used when the view was originally created.

Your fix is correct: make sure that you call all of your set methods AFTER you do your `holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution:

If you want to delete a row from a list view clicking on the DELETE button of each of that row do this. Here you have an example of a custom adapter class with a name and a delete button. Every time you press the button the row is deleted

public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

```
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();

public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,ArrayList<User> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    UserHolder holder = null;


    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new UserHolder();
        holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.btnDelete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();

    }

    User user = data.get(position);


    holder.btnDelete.setTag(position);
    holder.textName.setText(user.getName());



    holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String pos = v.getTag().toString();
            int _posicion = Integer.parseInt(pos);
            data.remove(_posicion);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    return row;


}

static class UserHolder {
    TextView textName;
    Button btnDelete;
}
```

}